# Nodejs exit on error, shoud prevent or not?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Nodejs in my windows machine. the question is Nodejs always terminate process on errors e.g. empty Mysql insert statement.

So in production time, and without manual error handling, how can prevent NodeJs exit?

example code:

```
app.post('/api/accounts',function(req,res){
 pool.getConnection(function(error,connection){
   connection.query('insert into accounts set ?',req.body,function(err,results){
   if (err) {
    throw err ;
   } else {
    console.log(results) ;
   }
  });
 });
 console.log('post received') ;
 console.log(req.body);
});
```

Imagine i post an empty req.body.
nodejs will exit on error like this

```
\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:77
    throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
    ^
```

Is it possible to configure something in node to just show errors but don't exit?

Comment: Show us some example code that does what you're talking about.

Comment: @John Zwinck:  I did update the post, thanks for attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really a good thing to be continuing execution after a **unhandled exception** has been thrown by the interpreter (as Ginden said in his answer) - anything could happen and it could prove to be a mistake later, any sort of hole could easily be opened by stopping the process from cleaning up after something went so unexpectedly wrong in your code.

You could **sensibly** add a event handler for `unhandledException` like the answer by Ginden points out, however, it seems you're using express and it would make much more sense actually handling the error with middleware when it happens, instead of using `throw` as per your code.

Replace `throw err;` with `return next(err);` and that should mean the request will fall through to the next set of middleware, which should then handle the error, do some logging, tell the user, whatever you want it to do.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // Maybe log the error for later reference?
    // If this is development, maybe show the stack here in this response?
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send({
        'message': err.message
    });
});
```

Comment: It was actually i wanted to know, so i learned how prevent stop with using next..., Thanks alot alot

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to prevent process shutdown. If error was thrown, **anything** could happen.

[Warning: Using 'uncaughtException' correctly](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/process.html#process_warning_using_uncaughtexception_correctly)

> Note that 'uncaughtException' is a crude mechanism for exception handling intended to be used only as a last resort. The event should not be used as an equivalent to On Error Resume Next. Unhandled exceptions inherently mean that an application is in an undefined state. Attempting to resume application code without properly recovering from the exception can cause additional unforeseen and unpredictable issues.
>   Exceptions thrown from within the event handler will not be caught. Instead the process will exit with a non zero exit code and the stack trace will be printed. This is to avoid infinite recursion.
>   Attempting to resume normally after an uncaught exception can be similar to pulling out of the power cord when upgrading a computer -- nine out of ten times nothing happens - but the 10th time, the system becomes corrupted.

[Domain module: don't ignore errors](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors).

> **By the very nature of how throw works in JavaScript, there is almost never any way to safely "pick up where you left off", without leaking references, or creating some other sort of undefined brittle state**.
>   The safest way to respond to a thrown error is to shut down the process. Of course, in a normal web server, you might have many connections open, and it is not reasonable to abruptly shut those down because an error was triggered by someone else.
>   The better approach is to send an error response to the request that triggered the error, while letting the others finish in their normal time, and stop listening for new requests in that worker.